# Suggestions for drawing a picture with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

Hello, I'm quite new to tikz and I'd like to draw something like this, any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome! What have you tried? I think that if you go through the first tutorial in the manual you'll be able to draw it, or at least have a preliminary version. Try it, and if you got stuck, come back with a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)!

Comment: In a quick search in google you can find something. But, as a new contributor and new in tikz. I suggest a reading in the manual chapter 13 about spherical coordinates, and search for examples as presented in:

http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/spherical-and-cartesian-grids/

Comment: My fast suggestion It is to use any online tool. In this site there are issues that relate to this request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conceptually similar to [Colo's nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/524419/194703) but using plain Ti*k*Z "only", and with elliptical arcs and bent arrows.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending,calc,decorations.markings,intersections}
\tikzset{% 
    attach arrow/.style={thick,
    decoration={
        markings,
         mark=at position 0 with {\pgfextra{%
         \pgfmathsetmacro{\tmpArrowTime}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arc arrow/length}/(\pgfdecoratedpathlength)}%
         \xdef\tmpArrowTime{\tmpArrowTime}}},
        mark=at position {#1-3*\tmpArrowTime} with {\coordinate(@1);},
        mark=at position {#1-2*\tmpArrowTime} with {\coordinate(@2);},
        mark=at position {#1-1*\tmpArrowTime} with {\coordinate(@3);},
        mark=at position {#1+\tmpArrowTime/2} with {\coordinate(@4);
        \draw[-{Stealth[length=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arc arrow/length},bend]}] plot[smooth]
         coordinates {(@1) (@2) (@3) (@4)};},
        },
     postaction=decorate,
     },
     attach arrow/.default=0.5,
     arc arrow/.cd,length/.initial=2mm,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={circle,fill,draw,inner sep=1.5pt,label=#1}]
 \path (0,2) coordinate[bullet={above:$y$}] (y)
 (0,-2) coordinate[bullet={below:$x$}] (x);
 \draw[thick,attach arrow,name path=a] (x) arc(270:90:2) node[midway,left]{$a$};
 \draw[thick,attach arrow,name path=b] (x) to[bend left=40] node[midway,right]{$b$} (y);
 \draw[thick,attach arrow] (x) to[bend right=40] node[midway,right]{$c$} (y);
 \draw[thick,attach arrow] (x) arc(-90:90:2) node[midway,right]{$d$};
 \foreach \X in {1,...,7}
 {\path[overlay,name path=h\X] (-2.2,-2+4*\X/7) -- (0,-2+4*\X/7);
 \draw[name intersections={of=a and h\X,by=il},
     name intersections={of=b and h\X,by=ir},dashed] 
    let \p1=($(ir)-(il)$) in (il) 
    arc[start angle=180,end angle=0,x radius=\x1/2,y radius=\x1/8]; 
 \draw[name intersections={of=a and h\X,by=il},
     name intersections={of=b and h\X,by=ir}] 
    let \p1=($(ir)-(il)$) in (il) 
    arc[start angle=180,end angle=360,x radius=\x1/2,y radius=\x1/8];   }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution via `tkz-euclid` and `tikz`.

The idea to get the small rings on the left (the most difficult part in my opinion) is to intersects different horizontal lines with the two arcs on the left side. I obtained this by `\tkzInterLC` which returns the desired intersections points (i.e `\tkzGetPoints{l'}{l}`). You have to discard one of them because it represents the second intersections points on the right side.

The horizontal line are on different levels:

```
\foreach \i in {.6,1.2,1.8}{
\tkzDefPoint(-1,\i){l}
\tkzDefPoint(1,\i){r}
    \tkzInterLC(l,r)(O,A)\tkzGetPoints{l'}{l}
    \tkzInterLC(l,r)(D,x)\tkzGetPoints{r'}{r}
  \draw (l) to[bend right] (r);
 \draw[dashed] (l) to[bend left] (r);
 }
```

I miss to find a solution to properly decorate the arcs with a nice arrows labels.Thus the command `\node[] (arrow) at (A) {$\wedge$};`needs to be improve.

Anyway, you get this

[image]

with

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}   

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoints{0/2/O,-2/2/A,2/2/D,0/4/y,0/0/x}
% main structure without arrows labels
\tkzDrawCircle(O,A)
\tkzDrawArc[color=black](D,y)(x)
\tkzDrawArc[color=black](A,x)(y)
% % nodes to get small rings
\foreach \i in {.6,1.2,1.8}{
\tkzDefPoint(-1,\i){l}
\tkzDefPoint(1,\i){r}
    \tkzInterLC(l,r)(O,A)\tkzGetPoints{l'}{l}
    \tkzInterLC(l,r)(D,x)\tkzGetPoints{r'}{r}
\draw (l) to[bend right] (r);
\draw[dashed] (l) to[bend left] (r);
}
% another loop needs because \tkzInterLC has two results (on the undesidered right side)
\foreach \i in {2.4,3,3.6}{
\tkzDefPoint(-1,\i){l}
\tkzDefPoint(1,\i){r}
    \tkzInterLC(l,r)(O,A)\tkzGetPoints{l'}{l}
    \tkzInterLC(l,r)(D,x)\tkzGetPoints{r'}{r}
\draw (l') to[bend right] (r');
\draw[dashed] (l') to[bend left] (r');
}
% bad but functional way to print the arrows
\node[] (arrow) at (A) {$\wedge$};
\node[] (arrow) at (D) {$\wedge$};
\node[] (arrow) at (-.82,2) {$\wedge$};
\node[] (arrow) at (.82,2) {$\wedge$};
% last labels
\tkzDrawPoints(x,y)
\tkzLabelPoint[left](A){$a$}
\tkzLabelPoint[right](D){$d$}
\tkzLabelPoints[above](y)
\tkzLabelPoints[below](x)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```